# How to configure Webpack to output assets into specific directories

Tags: webpack

At present Webpack is pushing everything (HTML, CSS, JS, etc) into the directory specified in `output.path`. Ideally I'd love to separate these out so that the assets contained in their own specific folder, whist maintaining the correct `src` attributes within `index.html` that is being generated by `html-webpack-plugin`.

For example:

```
build/
    index.html
    css/
        main.49587349.css
    js/
        vendor.52736973.js
        app.988734120.js
        vendor.52736973.map.js
        app.988734120.map.js
    img/
        image.jpg
        image.png
```

Is there a way that you're able to redirect your assets output into a more sensible directory structure? Or am I pushing too hard against the way Webpack want's me to work?

My current Webpack config is:

```
entry: {
        app: path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'app'),
        vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies)
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'build'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['babel'],
            include: path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'app'),
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: extractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css'),
            include: path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'app')
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlwebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Podcasting',
            template: './app/templates/index.html',
            inject: true,
            minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(
            'vendor',
            '[name].[chunkhash].js'
        ),
        new clean(['../build']),
        new extractTextPlugin('styles.[chunkhash].css'),
    ]
});
```

Comment: The joy of the Webpack build (for me) is that you don't really care about the output directory structure, only the path to the JS to put into your index.html (and CSS etc). All the other paths will resolve as required and you don't really need knowledge of the output as such. Having come from manual builds using gulp and grunt etc, I also felt the same way for a while.